# Running scripts in remote server using Rundeck 4.10

Tags: rundeck, sshj

I have Rundeck community version 4.10. I have some remote nodes where the job will run some scripts on remoe node to start applications. I used `SSHJ-SSH` configuration for my project under Rundeck for`Default Node Executor` and `Default File Copier`.

When I execute job from Rundeck on remote node to start application, its starting and within no time, the process is getting killed automatically and job status is shown as succeeded.

Are there any additional changes to be done on server also for rundeck configuration files?

Has any one got this issue?

Comment: Hi! Do you see any clue launching the job in the debug mode? Any clue in the service.log file?

Comment: Also, please share your node definition (resources.xml or resources.yaml) to take a look.

Comment: My nodes resources.xml file `<node name="host-name" description="Rundeck server node" tags="" hostname="host-name" osArch="amd64" osFamily="unix" osName="Linux" osVersion="4.4.0-36-generic" username="rundeck"/>
<node name="node1-name" description="Node - Description" tags="reg-test"
        hostname="node1-name" username="ubuntu"
        osFamily="unix" osName="Ubuntu">
 </node>
<node name="node2-name" description="Node - Description" tags="reg-test"
        hostname="node2-name" username="ubuntu"
        osFamily="unix" osName="Ubuntu">
 </node>`
my server node followed by remotenode

Comment: Like this I have many nodes in resources file. Some are ubuntu 18 and few ubuntu 22. And its not producing any logs and I don't see any info in my Application.Log file on remote node after executing the job from Rundeck. The job is executing successfully and its running script and starting app on remote node as it s showing in Activity of rundeck job execution. But when I check status of that app on remote node, it shows app is not running. This problem is same in both ubuntu 18 and ubuntu 22 nodes.

Comment: A job definition reproducible example would be good to reproduce the behavior. Additionally, did you set the shell interpreter on the inline-script / script step?

Comment: I changed Project configuration on Rundeck GUI. I used `OpenSSH/Executor with private key` option. Thenk it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

I changed Project configuration on Rundeck GUI. I used `OpenSSH/Executor with private key option`. Then it worked fine.